# Xamarin Forms - changing text on button with LabelSizeFontToFit effect makes text smaller and smaller

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, effects

I have a couple of buttons in an horizontal stack layout, and in order to accommodate different languages and the portrait orientation, I need the text size to accommodate the available space. Thus, I use the LabelSizeFontToFit effect (from the Xamarin.Toolkit.Effects NuGet package), as in the XAML code below.

```
<StackLayout x:Name="TitleBarLayout" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="Fill" VerticalOptions="Fill" Spacing="0" Padding="0" Margin="0" BackgroundColor="LightGoldenrodYellow" >
    <Button x:Name="AddSelected" FontSize="Default" HorizontalOptions="End" TextColor="White" VerticalOptions="Center" BackgroundColor="Blue" Margin="0" Padding="0" Clicked="AddSelected_Clicked" >
        <Button.Effects>
            <effects:LabelSizeFontToFit />
        </Button.Effects>
    </Button>
    <Button x:Name="DeleteSelected" FontSize="Default" HorizontalOptions="End" TextColor="White" VerticalOptions="Center" BackgroundColor="Red" Margin="0" Padding="0" Clicked="DeleteSelected_Clicked" >
        <Button.Effects>
            <effects:LabelSizeFontToFit />
        </Button.Effects>
    </Button>
</StackLayout>
```

This works correctly initially. However, I need to switch the text on these buttons between two different strings depending on whether one or more items are selected. Unfortunately, every time I change the text in the C# code-behind the text gets smaller. As I select and deselect different things, it eventually gets illegibly small. It makes no sense because once the font is small enough to accommodate both strings it shouldn't get any smaller.

I've tried all sorts of combinations of layout parameters to no avail.

Does anyone know why it behaves like this and how to make it behave correctly?

PS I've tried a couple of other shrink-font-to-fit methods and they're a lot messier and difficult to use. I don't want to use Forms9Patch because it increases my package size by 35%.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Xamarin.Toolkit.Effects, will not scale up a font size, only down.To resolve this problem, I suggest you can create custom Button, custombtn extends Xamarin.Forms.Button and adds the following two methods:

```
   public class custombtn:Button
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Autosizes the button's font size with regards to it's container size.
    /// </summary>
    private void AutoFontSize()
    {
        //determine the text height for the min font size
        double lowerFontSize = 15;
        double lowerTextHeight = TextHeightForFontSize(lowerFontSize);

        //determine the text height for the max font size
        double upperFontSize = 30;
        double upperTextHeight = TextHeightForFontSize(upperFontSize);

        //start a loop which'll find the optimal font size
        while (upperFontSize - lowerFontSize > 1)
        {
            //determine current average font size and calculate corresponding text height
            double fontSize = (lowerFontSize + upperFontSize) / 2;
            double textHeight = TextHeightForFontSize(upperFontSize);

            //if the calculated height is out of bounds, update max values, else update min values
            if (textHeight > Height)
            {
                upperFontSize = fontSize; upperTextHeight = textHeight;
            }
            else
            {
                lowerFontSize = fontSize; lowerTextHeight = textHeight;
            }
        }

        //finally set the correct font size
        FontSize = lowerFontSize;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Determines the text height for the label with a given font size.
    /// </summary>
    private double TextHeightForFontSize(double fontSize)
    {
        FontSize = fontSize;
        return OnMeasure(Width, Double.PositiveInfinity).Request.Height;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Callback when the size of the element is set during a layout cycle.
    /// </summary>
    protected override void OnSizeAllocated(double width, double height)
    {
        //call base implementation
        base.OnSizeAllocated(width, height);

        //update font size
        AutoFontSize();
    }

    new public string Text
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); AutoFontSize(); }
    }

}
```

MinFontSize and MaxFontSize properties can be added so that the min/max font size values can be specified in XAML.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not asking it to scale the font up, just not to scale it down for no reason. I'll try your code out after work.

Comment: I've tried that solution and it works a treat. Thank you!

Comment: Did you mean: double textHeight = TextHeightForFontSize(fontSize); ?